# fillRect drawing wrong shape in HTML canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I'm using a html `canvas` element in my chrome app but `fillRect` won't work. It prints a solid rectangle but incorrectly.

I did this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

but it looks like this:

[image: it looks like this]

it should look like this

[image: It should look like this]

What kind of problem is this?

CSS?

```
#canvas {
  width: 896px;
  height: 896px;
  background-image: url('assets/underlays/transUnderlay_28.png');
}
```

HTML?

```
<td>
  <div id='canvasWrapper'>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `height` and `width` in the `<canvas>` element other than in the CSS:

```
<td>
  <div id='canvasWrapper'>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='896' height='896' ></canvas>
  </div>
</td>
```

For the HTML 5 canvas the `width` and `height` attributes are for setting the actual width/height for the canvas's coordinate system, while the normal CSS `width` and `height` as just the size of the element (not respect to the elements coordinate system).